# Count number of rows with different columns from two equal columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have the following table, which has origin/destination cities and extra cities that are stops on the origin-destination route. This is an example for origin Augsburg and destinationn Telfs.

| origin | destination | city | city.1 | city.2 | city.3 | city.4 | city.5 | city.6 | city.7 | city.8 | city.9 | city.10 | city.11 | city.12 | city.13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf | Ilshofen |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf | Ilshofen | Reutte | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf | Ilshofen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Augsburg | Telfs | Augsburg | Telfs | Löffingen | Todtmoos | Remseck | Heilbronn | Ottersweier | Imst | Feldkirchen | Wien | Hermagor | Aichdorf | Ilshofen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

What I want from this table is to obtain the number of different existing routes, that is, the number of routes where the same stopping cities are not repeated. For example in this case it would be 11 (because one row doesnt have any city different to the origin/destination).
I want to build a table like this:

| Origin | Destination | Number of routes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Augsburg | Telfs | 11 |

any idea or solution?

to reproduce dataframe : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nFLb0yCP24lcbFqqYRt5bq6yttjQNxGh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What's with the block of `NaN`s in your table? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) either as a copy-paste-able Pandas DataFrame (i.e., able to be used via `pd.read_clipboard()`, or as code to reproduce your DataFrame.

Comment: in the database where i extract the cities information, some fields where nan

Comment: in the question there is a dict to reproduce de df

Comment: The dict you provided doesn't match your formatted table. Using the dict you provided I get 13 rows where `city` is `Augsburg` and the last defined `city.X` is unique.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nFLb0yCP24lcbFqqYRt5bq6yttjQNxGh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do the provided solutions answer your question? If so, please consider upvoting all helpful answers and marking one as correct, so that your answer can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one potential solution, with columns named `"origin"` and `"destination"`:

```py
def get_start_and_end(row):
    return row[row.last_valid_index()]


def get_number_of_unique_routes_by_group(group):
    return len(group.apply(get_start_and_end, axis=1).unique())


df.groupby(["origin", "destination"]).apply(get_number_of_unique_routes_by_group)
```

Output:

```py
origin    destination
Augsburg  Telfs          13
dtype: int64
```

Your example dataframe only included one such group, but if you had other origin-destination groupings, they'd show up in the output too.

Comment: it doesnt work :(.  Input In [188], in get_number_of_unique_routes_by_group(group)
      5 def get_number_of_unique_routes_by_group(group):
----> 6     return len(group.apply(get_start_and_end, axis=1)).unique()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: Then something is wrong on your end; I copied the data you provided in your drive file, and only renamed the first two columns to `"origin"` and `"destination"`.

Comment: it was de parenthesis, it has to be:  return len(group.apply(get_start_and_end, axis=1).unique())

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: Here is a code that identifies there are 13 unique routes not 11.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if not 'Unnamed' in x]]
df = df.assign(hash=df.apply(lambda x: hash("".join(x.fillna("")[1:])), axis=1))
df.groupby(["origin", "destination", "hash"])["city"].count().count()
```